# CameraStream Actions on Google

Tags: actions-on-google, google-smart-home

I am trying to integrate camera to my smarthome with google assistant. I followed [CameraStream](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/traits/camerastream#request) in actions on google. i have synced my camera and tried execute and responding with an URL(cameraStreamAccessUrl).

Command: "show camera"

google home reply: "Sure, streaming camera" <-- but it is not streaming the video.

Command: "show camera on my phone"

google home reply: "Sorry, i don't know where to play the video. Please tell me the exact name of the screen"

My question is how can i stream it on my phone or on the app?

execution request google json:

```
{
  "inputs": [
  "intent": "action.devices.EXECUTE",
  "payload": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "devices": [
          {
            "customData": {
              "barValue": true,
              "bazValue": "lambtwirl",
              "fooValue": 74
            },
            "id": "id"
          }
        ],
        "execution": [
          {
            "command": "action.devices.commands.GetCameraStream",
            "params": {
              "StreamToChromecast": false,
              "SupportedStreamProtocols": [
                "hls"
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}], "requestId": "requestId"
}
```

my json response:

```
{
  "requestId": "requestId",
  "payload": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "ids": [
          "requestId"
        ],
        "status": "SUCCESS",
        "states": {
          "cameraStreamAccessUrl": "https://url.url"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Chromecast in your home, the Google Home will forward the video stream to the Chromecast. I don't know where the stream would go if you don't have a display.

Saying "on my phone" is not a valid target from a Google Home. To get it on your phone, you'd need to use the Assistant on your phone or the Google Home App.